# How to move a sprite relative to another sprite's rotation?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game I have a rocket sprite and at the bottom of the rocket there is an animated flame sprite , I want the flame sprite to align with the bottom of the rocket when the rocket rotates.

This is the rocket when the game starts, everything is OK:

[image: Initial position]

But when i rotate the rocket the flame does not align with the rocket's bottom like this:

[image: After rotation]

How can i make it align?

here is my code:

```
    // draw rocket
    rocketSprite.setRegion(AssetLoader.rocketTexture);
    rocketSprite.setPosition(rocket.getX(), rocket.getY());
    rocketSprite.setOrigin(rocket.getWidth() / 2, rocket.getHeight() / 2);
    rocketSprite.setSize(rocket.getWidth(), rocket.getHeight());
    rocketprite.setRotation(rocket.getRotation());
    rocketSprite.setScale(1, 1);
    rocketPodSprite.draw(game.batch);


    //flame width and height
    int w = 70;
    int h = 20;

    // randomly change scale of flame for effects
    float sw = MathUtils.random(2f / 7f, 1);
    float sh = MathUtils.random(0.5f, 1);

    // draw flame
    flameSprite.setRegion(AssetLoader.flameTexture);
    flameSprite.setPosition(rocket.getX() + rocket.getWidth() / 2 - w, rocket.getY() - 15);
    flameSprite.setOrigin(w, h / 2);
    flameSprite.setSize(w, h);
    flameSprite.setRotation(rocket.getRotation());
    flameSprite.setScale(sw, sh);
    flameSprite.draw(game.batch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `origin` - point arround which your sprite will be rotated.

Your problem is that both rocket and flame are rotated arround their own centres however you would rather like to rotate them both arround rocket's one. Then you need to set the flame sprite origin with position of rocket center.

```
    flameSprite.setOrigin(w, h / 2 + rocket.getHeight() / 2 + SPACE_BETWEEN_ROCKET_AND_FLAME);
```

---

As I see in your case the `SPACE_BETWEEN_ROCKET_AND_FLAME` has value of `15 - flame.height` due to this position set:

```
    flameSprite.setPosition(rocket.getX() + rocket.getWidth() / 2 - w, rocket.getY() - 15);
```

Comment: When I do that my sprite moves to a different position. and I want to use the top center of the flame to randomly scale the flame sprite. Maybe there is a formula I can use to translate the flame relative to the rockets position?

Comment: Hm what does it mean that it moves to a different position? As far as I know the origin has nothing common with position so it should not act as that - can you plase share some screenshot? If we are talking about another options I think that you should be able to translate your flame properly with using Vector2 object and rotation although I'm pretty surprised that origin manipulation is not enough...